# Count the occurence of each word in a text file by Perl

Tags: perl

I want to calculate the occurence of each word in a text file by using Perl. this is the script :

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl -w
#Exercice 8

#Ouvrir le fichier
open my($file), '<', 'file.txt' 
or die "Erreur lors de l'ouverture";

#Afficher le fichier  
while( my $line = <$file> ) {
        chomp($line) ;
        print "$line \n";
}

#Calculer le nombre d'apparaition
while( my $line = <$file> ){
foreach $word (split(' ',$line)){
    $freq{$word}++;
}
}

#Afficher les mots en ordre
foreach $word (sort keys %freq) {
print "$word $freq{$word}\n";
}
```

When I run the script I only get the result of the first loop as result.
The two others don't return any output.

Comment: because the 1st cycle **consumes** the all of input lines from the `$file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first loop, you read all the file's lines via the `<>` operator, which means that you essentially advance the file pointer to the end of the file.

In your second loop, you are using the `<>` operator once again, but to no avail - you have consumed the whole file in your previous loop, so there is nothing else left to read. `%freq` is therefore uninitialized in your final loop.

I would recommend merging loops 1 and 2, like this:

```
while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
     chomp($line);
     print $line; 
     foreach $word (split(' ', $line)) {
         $freq{$word}++;
     }
}
```